# Web Scraping within Links using Scrapy

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, scrapy

I am web-scraping information from a site that has several pages of data. Within each scrape, I am extracting a handful of information. However, I want to also go inside the link of what I am scraping and scrape information from there as well and then return back to the site and continue scraping. How would I do this using Scrapy?

Comment: Hi Sad Toad, could you please show us what you have tried already and what website you are trying to crawl? Please update your question so people can help you.

Comment: Let's call page has results list index_page; let's call page has detail data detail_page, so you want to extract detail_page urls from index_page, then you want go to detail_page scrape detail data? You don't know how to go to detail_page through scrapy?

Comment: if you want to get data from main page and from details page to create one row of data then you can use `Request(url_to_details, meta={"data":data_from_main_page}, parse_details})`. But you don't want to create one row from many pages then you ask for knowledege which you can find in any tutorial or documentation and you only waste time for asking it.

Answer (score 0):

CrawlSpider library can be used along with scrapy to recursively crawl through a huge graph of web pages.

More information:

[Crawling a site recursively using scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501458/crawling-a-site-recursively-using-scrapy/40146588)

https://realpython.com/web-scraping-and-crawling-with-scrapy-and-mongodb/

https://mherman.org/blog/recursively-scraping-web-pages-with-scrapy/

Answer (score 0):

You could use **recursion** to achieve the desired objective. Start by scraping a start link, and then recursively iterate the links inside it and it goes on. Beware that this recursion might take very long, and might eventually ban your **scraper** in some cases. Try limiting the recursion depth to 2 or 3.

Code Snippet:

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.http import Request

class MyItem(Item):
    url= Field()

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'twitter.com'
    allowed_domains = ['twitter.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.twitter.com']

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_url', follow=False), )

    def parse_url(self, response):
        item = MyItem()

        ## Do your processing here

        item['url'] = response.url
        request = Request(response.url)
        yield request
```